# How can MySQL's data types with 4GB limits be fully used since max_allowed_packet is hard limited to 1GB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The MySQL types [`LONGTEXT` and `LONGBLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) are documented with data limits of L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32 (~4GB). But [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is [only configurable up to 1GB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html).

> The largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a MySQL
>   8.0 server or client is 1GB.

Wouldn't that mean the limit of LONGTEXT and LONGBLOG is actually ~1GB? The [JSON type is limited by `max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-json) but the text/blob types do not mention the same limitation. Are there ways to work with those types, maybe in fragments, to work within the packet limit?

Note: I understand storing data larger than 1MB in a DB column is discouraged for performance and design reasons. I'm just wondering how I'd ever store or retrieve more than 1GB in a TEXT/BLOB if it's ever required.

Comment: Not network packet size, but [how MySQL defines a packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html): "a single SQL statement sent to the MySQL server, a single row that is sent to the client, or a binary log event sent from a master replication server to a slave."

Comment: Misunderstood, sorry about that. Interesting question then indeed.

Comment: Give it a try, as far as i know, it doesn't matter as long as you connection holds it woukd send data and mysql can handle ot, but i never tried such big data. only smaler files. Set the max packet size tio 1 MB and send 4 . It will work. but as i said give it a try

Comment: There are many restrictions and _practical_ limitations.  I would not try to get anywhere near 1GB.

Answer (score 1):

In this [MySQL bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103387) a member of the verification team responds and says:

> this problem is easily solved by using chunks with prepared statements. Some of our client programs do support this feature.

So as a naive chunking solution we could try something like:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (bigcol) VALUES (@chunk1); 
SET @id := last_insert_id();
UPDATE table1 SET bigcol = concat(bigcol, @chunk2) WHERE id = @id;
UPDATE table1 SET bigcol = concat(bigcol, @chunk3) WHERE id = @id;
UPDATE table1 SET bigcol = concat(bigcol, @chunk4) WHERE id = @id;
```

I've tested this with a smaller value, 1024, for `max_allowed_packet` and the same size for each chunk. It doesn't work, at least not if you use the `mariadb` command-line client, so presumably the same with the `mysql` client. Each `UPDATE` fails with:

> ERROR 1301 (HY000): Result of concat() was larger than max_allowed_packet (1024) - truncated

It makes no difference if we use prepared statements.

However, if using the C API, there is a method `mysql_stmt_send_long_data()`, documented by both [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-stmt-send-long-data.html) and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_stmt_send_long_data/), which can supposedly chunk the data for you and avoid the limit.

So, there you have it - there is a way to do this, but it's not supported by the command-line clients.